# SQL Standard Value and Variations

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Below is a sample of data

```
UnitID     ITEM_Num     Price  
13446      71079        45.57  
13447      71079        45.57  
13448      71079        52.50  
13449      71079        45.57  
13450      71079        36.22
```

The actual dataset has roughly 100 unique UnitIDs and 700 unique Item_Num values. I am trying to determine the most common price for each Item_Num and then select any records that vary from that standard by more than a specified percent.

Ideally we would have a standard Price value for each item but we don't.  What is the best way to find the most common value.  Also is there a function that might be able to quickly rank the Items with the most variation is Price.

This is SQL Server 2012.

Comment: group by price, order by count(*) desc, limit 1 or something

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY statement:

```
SELECT Price, count(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY Price ORDER BY Price ASC
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: true, i revised the answer

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work in SQL Server. It should give back each ITEM_Num with a price 10% lower or higher than the most common price.

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_Num ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC) AS 'Rank'
  , ITEM_Num
  , Price     
  FROM Units
  GROUP BY ITEM_Num, Price 
)
SELECT u1.UnitID
,      u1.ITEM_Num
,      u1.Price
,      u2.Price AS 'most common price'
FROM Units u1
INNER JOIN cte AS u2
ON u2.ITEM_Num = u1.ITEM_Num
AND u2.Rank = 1
WHERE ABS(u1.Price - u2.Price) >=  (u2.Price * 0.1);
```

EDIT: I wrote the query not knowing your DBMS, could probably be more efficient using the ranking functions of SQL Server.

EDIT 2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74940/33

Comment: My DBMS is SQL server.  The derived table in the join only returns one value.  I understand the concept but the syntax isn't working.  I should be getting the Price with the highest count of items with the same price but I am not.  Should I use over and Row_number?

Comment: `I am trying to determine the most common price for each Item_Num and then select any records that vary from that standard by more than a specified percent.` The subquery retrieves the most common price. The outer query selects any records that vary from the standard by more than a specified percent (in my case 10%).

Comment: But the it has to be the most common price per item not the most common price of the entire dataset.

Comment: You were correct, I did not test it with 2 different items. I updated the script with the use of RANK() and tested it using multiple items. You can see my SQL Fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table #t(
UnitID int,

Item_Num int,
Price money
)

Insert into #t(Unitid, Item_Num, Price)
values(13446,      71079,        45.57 ),
(13447,      71079,        45.57), 
(13448,      71079,        52.50), 
(13449,      71079,        45.57),
(13450,      71079,        36.22)



;with cte as (
Select 
Unitid, Item_Num, Price, 
Row_Number() over ( partition by item_num order by price) rownum
from #t
) 

Select 
u.UnitID,
u.Item_Num,
u.Price,
U1.price as CommonPrice,
u.RowNum,
U.Price*0.1,
(u.price +(u.price*0.1)) as NewPrice
from cte as U
inner join #t u1 on u.item_num =u1.item_num

where u.rownum =1
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a new set of rownumbers each time the price changed?  I don't see how it ranks the most common price value.